# reactivating a query after executing an insert statement in PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2  forms. The first form the user would select a department (DEPQ) from a drop down menu list. Once that is done they would submit that form and the results would be displayed in a drop down menu  in the second form. The user would then use this second form to insert data into a table in msql database using the derived values. What I am trying to do is once the system has completed the insertion of the data, the system automatically re populates the drop down menu with the results derived from first query. I know this can be simply achieved with multiple linked drop down menu's but I have been unable to find a suitable tutorial for this function. Any help you all can give me would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try this: http://remysharp.com/2007/01/20/auto-populating-select-boxes-using-jquery-ajax/

Answer (score -1):

Well you have to implement any opportunity to identify the user. Maybe a user system, maybe only a cookie/localstorage or something else. Important is, that the user can by identified with an unique id.

In the next step you create a mysql table where you save the first selection of the user may be in this format

```
id | user_id | department
-------------------------
1  | 3       | depA
2  | 15      | depB
```

Then when the user visits your page again, you identifie the user and populate the select element.

Comment: I hope this is what you are trying to achive. If not please clarify your question.